# Open file with spacemacs as default

Tags: macos, emacs, spacemacs

I recently switched my editor to spacemacs, and i have been enjoying it so far. The only thorn in my side is when i try to choose what program to open a file type i get this error:

> **You can't change the item "10g.fsx" to
>   always open in the selected application.**
>
> The item is either locked or damaged, or in a folder
>   you don't have permission to modify (error code
>   -9499).

[(Fugly screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UayST.png)

The only thing i can think of is when i installed spacemacs, following their guide on installing emacs as well, brew gives me a warning that using linkapps well make emacs not searchable from spotlight. When i check my applications folder emacs appears as "alias" instead of "application".
Could this be the problem, and is there a solution for it?

I have also found out that it only applies to my .fs and .fsx files for f#. Setting a .java to use emacs as default is no issue.

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as images. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: The error message indicates it can't change 10g.fsx. Please [edit] the question to update it with pertinent details about applicable permissions and attributes for this item.